# List of ggplot2 theme options?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After some research I found the way to prevent an uninformative legend from displaying

```
... + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Where can I find all of the available `theme` options and their default values for ggplot2?

Comment: Is @hadley aware of this question? I just went looking on the ggplot2 website, expecting to find this info - or at least a description of what `opts()` does. Anyway, there's a list (not sure it's complete) in the built-in help: `?opts`

Comment: `opts` is deprecated, it's now `+ theme()`

Comment: Best list I've found for version 0.9.2.1 is: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The closest thing to a comprehensive list that I have been able to find is in the [ggplot2 wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/-opts%28%29----theme%28%29-List) on github. I think that most of the options are covered there with examples.

**Update**
If you would like to see the options that are in use on a current plot, you can use `plot_theme(x)` to see all of the options that are currently set for the plot named x. It will not be a comprehensive list, but should help if you want to change something like the font size for an axis label.

**Update 2**
With the transition to version 0.9.0 it's worth noting that the built in documentation has been dramatically improved, and the [transition guide](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2-dev/iiS6tMF0fhk) from 0.8.9 to 0.9.0 is also worth checking out.

**Update 3**
There is now a ggplot2 documentation website. Look at the documentation for [theme](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) for a complete list. Also, `?theme` has a pretty complete list as of 0.9.3.

**Update 4**
There is now a ggthemes package that has some nice themes and scales to choose from. It might save you from having to create your own. See their [github](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes) page for more information.

Comment: Agreed. This is probably the best publicly available list nowadays.  A lot can change in a year!

Answer (score 23):

Entering in

```
theme_get()
```

will show a comprehensive listing of theme values and options.  You can then follow the syntax to modify these attributes in opts().

Answer (score 13):

The `ggplot2` package does not contain much reference information-- this is probably because Hadley has put a lot of work into developing and polishing the package, creating a website full of examples and writing an excellent book that describes the system in detail.

The first place I would look for answers would be the `ggplot2` website:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/

However, since `opts()` is not really a geom, stat or scale there are no examples that focus specifically on it.  The next place to look would be the section of the website that contains material from the book-- including source code for examples:

http://ggplot2.org/book/

The example code for the chapter "Polishing your plots for publication" contains some well commented examples of using `set_theme()` and `opts()` to alter plot appearance.

The ultimate source for information is of course the book it's self.  If you find `ggplot2` has simplified and streamlined your workflow for producing statistical graphics, buying a copy of the book is a great way to say "thank you" and support the further development of the package.

> **Update**

After some further investigation, you may be able to find a relatively complete list of options by listing out the source of one of the "theme" functions such as `theme_bw`.  The source doesn't provide a description of the possible `key=value` pairs, but it does at least show most of the `key` names that have an effect when set via `opts()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was expecting to find something like this (but for ggplot2 of course) http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ggplot/html/build-options-8a.html

Comment: Hmm, a list of options (complete?) is also included on page 39 here http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book.pdf

Comment: That table describes most of the options-- the master list seems to be table 8.1 in the full book.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the obvious references to [ggplot2 reference manual](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) and to the [graphs section of Cookbook for R](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/), Hadley Wickham provides a nice opts() List on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/-opts%28%29-List).

Answer (score 4):

**Theme templates:**

https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes

like "The economist", "Stata", "tufte" and more..

I know the answer is not exactly what was asked, but it was what I was looking for when I found this question, so others might too.

Answer (score 1):

All the options I've ever used have been explained in hadley's great ggplot2 book.

Answer (score 1):

Best list I've found for version 0.9.2.1 is [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html).

Answer (score 0):

`?opts`
although, this does not display how to finetune its arguments, therefore it's better to check the options given above. If you can get a copy of the ggplot2 reference manual, it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick reference for any [theme or tasks](http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-cheatsheet.html) you might look for. For a more general understanding, this [ggplot2 tutorial](http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-Tutorial-With-R.html) should help.