# How can I manipulate the strip text of facet_grid plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm wondering how I can manipulate the size of strip text in facetted plots. My question
is similar to [a question on plot titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631780/r-ggplot2-can-i-set-the-plot-title-to-wrap-around-and-shrink-the-text-to-fit-th), but I'm specifically concerned with
manipulating not the plot title but the text that appears in facet titles (strip_h).

As an example, consider the mpg dataset.

```
    library(ggplot2) 
    qplot(hwy, cty, data = mpg) + facet_grid( . ~ manufacturer)
```

The resulting [output](http://skitch.com/capbri/dbx1n/quartz-2) produces some facet titles that don't fit in the strip.

I'm thinking there must be a way to use `grid` to deal with the strip text. But I'm
still a novice and wasn't sure from the `grid` appendix in [Hadley's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387981403) how,
precisely, to do it.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can modify `strip.text.x` (or `strip.text.y`) using `theme_text()`, for instance

```
qplot(hwy, cty, data = mpg) + 
      facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer) + 
      opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size = 8, colour = "red", angle = 90))
```

**Update:** for ggplot2 version > 0.9.1

```
qplot(hwy, cty, data = mpg) + 
      facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer) + 
      theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, colour = "red", angle = 90))
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. Is there a way to improve also the x axis annotation?

Comment: Thanks rcs. I'm with gd047, and perhaps that should be a separate question? What you're noticing is the crowding of major x-values, I think.

There should be a way to set the values of the major x-axis and y-axis tick marks manually, but I can't remember what it is :-(

Comment: @gd047: `axis.text.x=theme_text(...)`

Comment: Links in this Q should be somewhat informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258784/list-of-ggplot2-options

Comment: Does this change the text, or the box the text is written in.  Because I just get a big box.

Answer (score 37):

Nowadays the usage of `opts` and `theme_text` seems to be deprecated. R suggests to use `theme` and `element_text`. A solution to the answer can be found here: http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Facets%20%28ggplot2%29/#modifying-facet-label-text

```
qplot(hwy, cty, data = mpg) + 
      facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer) + 
      theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, colour = "red", angle = 90))
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess in the example of `mpg` changing the rotation angle and font size is fine, but in many cases you might find yourself with variables that have quite lengthy labels, and it can become a pain in the neck (literally) to try read rotated lengthy labels.

So in addition (or complement) to changing angles and sizes, I usually reformat the labels of the factors that define the `facet_grid` whenever they can be split in a way that makes sense.

Typically if I have a `dataset$variable` with strings that looks like

```
c("median_something", "aggregated_average_x","error","something_else")
```

I simply do:

```
reformat <– function(x,lab="\n"){ sapply(x, function(c){ paste(unlist(strsplit(as.character(c) , split="_")),collapse=lab) }) }
```

[perhaps there are better definitions of `reformat` but at least this one works fine.]

```
dataset$variable <- factor(dataset$variable, labels=reformat(dataset$variable, lab='\n')
```

And upon facetting, all labels will be very readable:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

Comment: Maybe something like this is better:  levels(birds$effect) <- gsub(" ", "\n", levels(birds$effect))