# how to change strip.text labels in ggplot with facet and margin=TRUE

Tags: r, label, locale, ggplot2, facet

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751065/how-can-i-manipulate-the-strip-text-of-facet-plots-in-ggplot2) but still can't figure it out. How do I change the strip.text.x labels in a ggplot with faceting? Specifically I am using facet_grid with margins. The strip.text label for the margin is "(all)" - but since I am in a non-english speaking country I would rather write "Total" or something similar in my native tongue.

```
opts(stip.text.x=c(levels(facetvariabel,"Total")) does not work.
```

Any ideas?

Example (not really the best dataset for this - but I guess it will work)

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist))+geom_bar()+facet_grid(.~speed, margin=T)
```

Comment: Duplicate: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels

Comment: @naught101 Just to be clear - this question was asked in may, while the other question was asked in august.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize the facet labels by giving labeller function:

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  if (x == "speed")
    c(y[-length(y)], "Total")
  else
    y
}

ggplot(cars, aes(x = dist)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(. ~ speed, margin = TRUE, labeller = f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - I tried labeller - but was thrown of... This was very helpfull. My final solution needed paste though:
f<-function(x,y){if(x=="spped"){c(paste(y[-length(y)]), "Total")} else y}
Thanks again!!!