# How to change facet labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols, facet, plotmath

I have used the following `ggplot` command:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(x = age)) + stat_bin(aes(n = nrow(h3), y = ..count.. / n), binwidth = 10)
  + scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent", breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2))
  + facet_grid(hospital ~ .)
  + theme(panel.background = theme_blank())
```

to produce

[image]

I'd like to change the *facet* labels, however, to something shorter (like `Hosp 1`, `Hosp 2`...) because they are too long now and look cramped (increasing the height of the graph is not an option, it would take too much space in the document). I looked at the [facet_grid](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) help page but cannot figure out how.

Comment: Most answers are very verbose. I found a simple answer (https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-sep-in-labeller/7369/2), and made an example with it. See down below.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Change the underlying factor level names with something like:

```
# Using the Iris data
> i <- iris
> levels(i$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
> levels(i$Species) <- c("S", "Ve", "Vi")
> ggplot(i, aes(Petal.Length)) + stat_bin() + facet_grid(Species ~ .)
```

Comment: @wishihadabettername: To avoid changing underlying data, you can use:
 `ggplot(transform(iris, Species = c("S", "Ve", "Vi")[as.numeric(Species)]), aes(Petal.Length)) + stat_bin() + facet_grid(Species ~ .)`

Comment: related... if you want the panel label to be a bquote() expression (e.g., `levels(x$measurements) <- c(bquote(Area ~~ (cm^2)), bquote(Length ~~ (cm)))`) it will not appear in mathematical expression. How would one show expressions as facet labels?

Comment: related for including expressions in the facet label, use `labeller` option to `facet_grid`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089052/r-ggplot2-facet-grid-how-include-math-expressions-in-few-not-all-labels

Answer (score 336):

Here is a solution that avoids editing your data:

Say your plot is facetted by the `group` part of your dataframe, which has levels `control, test1, test2`, then create a list named by those values:

```
hospital_names <- list(
  'Hospital#1'="Some Hospital",
  'Hospital#2'="Another Hospital",
  'Hospital#3'="Hospital Number 3",
  'Hospital#4'="The Other Hospital"
)
```

Then create a 'labeller' function, and push it into your facet_grid call:

```
hospital_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(hospital_names[value])
}

ggplot(survey,aes(x=age)) + stat_bin(aes(n=nrow(h3),y=..count../n), binwidth=10)
 + facet_grid(hospital ~ ., labeller=hospital_labeller)
 ...
```

This uses the levels of the data frame to index the hospital_names list, returning the list values (the correct names).

---

Please note that this only works if you only have one faceting variable. If you have two facets, then your labeller function needs to return a different name vector for each facet. You can do this with something like :

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  if (variable=='facet1') {
    return(facet1_names[value])
  } else {
    return(facet2_names[value])
  }
}
```

Where `facet1_names` and `facet2_names` are pre-defined lists of names indexed by the facet index names ('Hostpital#1', etc.).

---

**Edit:** The above method fails if you pass a variable/value combination that the labeller doesn't know. You can add a fail-safe for unknown variables like this:

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  if (variable=='facet1') {
    return(facet1_names[value])
  } else if (variable=='facet2') {
    return(facet2_names[value])
  } else {
    return(as.character(value))
  }
}
```

---

Answer adapted from [how to change strip.text labels in ggplot with facet and margin=TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893005/how-to-change-strip-text-labels-in-ggplot-with-facet-and-margin-true)

---

<del>edit: **WARNING**: if you're using this method to facet by a *character* column, you may be getting incorrect labels. See [this bug report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1070).</del> fixed in recent versions of ggplot2.

Comment: Nice, but will not work with facet_wrap, whereas @Vince solution will work with facet_wrap too.

Comment: @ArnaudAmzallag: Correct, though if someone feels like donating some time, [it could in the future](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/25).

Comment: Added a fail-safe for unknown facetting variables.

Comment: Notice: This does not work in ggplot2 v.2 - the labeller function has changed. @mbirons answer works http://stackoverflow.com/a/34811062/162832

Comment: Interesting, but this doesn't always work, whereas editing the factors always does.

Comment: Should the higher order variable be repeated in facet1_names?

Comment: Can we update this since the labeller used here is now deprecated?

Answer (score 304):

Here's another solution that's in the spirit of [the one given by @naught101](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104207), but simpler and also does not throw a warning on the latest version of ggplot2.

Basically, you first create a named character vector

```
hospital_names <- c(
                    `Hospital#1` = "Some Hospital",
                    `Hospital#2` = "Another Hospital",
                    `Hospital#3` = "Hospital Number 3",
                    `Hospital#4` = "The Other Hospital"
                    )
```

And then you use it as a labeller, just by modifying the last line of the code given by @naught101 to

```
... + facet_grid(hospital ~ ., labeller = as_labeller(hospital_names))
```

Comment: Which verison of ggplot2 is `as_labeller` in? I have found some source code for on the [CRAN GitHub repository](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/facet-labels.r), but after upgrading to the latest version (on CRAN!) I don't seem to have the function.

Comment: That's weird. I also updated through CRAN. Here is the documentation http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/as_labeller.html

Comment: This is cool. What happens when you have two variables in your facet grid though? Like `hospital ~ gender` or something? Is there a way to use labellers on both axes? I can't see anything obvious in the docs.

Comment: Note if you started with naught's answer, this one only works with a **c()** not a **list()**.

Comment: One great part of this is that this works with both axes of the facet grid!

Comment: an answer to @naught101 's question would be the answer by domi : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37778906/8124725 Without this addition, this doesn't work for me, yielding NA's for the variable that I did not include.

Comment: How to do this if you have two facets though?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor check out [@bovender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913120/5443023)

Comment: @mbiron yeah but its two X facets not X and Y

Answer (score 53):

The EASIEST way to change WITHOUT modifying the underlying data is:

1. Create an object using `as_labeller()`. If the column names begin with a number or contain spaces or special characters, don't forget to use back tick marks:

```
# Necessary to put RH% into the facet labels
hum_names <- as_labeller(
     c(`50` = "RH% 50", `60` = "RH% 60",`70` = "RH% 70", 
       `80` = "RH% 80",`90` = "RH% 90", `100` = "RH% 100"))
```

2. Add to the ggplot:

```
    ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = Temperature.C, y = fit)) + 
        geom_line() + 
        facet_wrap(~Humidity.RH., nrow = 2, labeller = hum_names)
```

Comment: This I think is the most elegant method -- it is effective and works with ggplot2 version 3.0.0.9000

Comment: but it does not work when there are two facets, e.g., type~Humidity

Comment: @DenisCousineau in that case use `labeller = labeller(Type = c(...), Humidity = c(...))` where the ... are the key value pairs

Comment: Also I'd note that if you are just prefixing everything with `RH%`, a more robust solution would be to replace step 1 in this answer with `hum_names <- as_labeller(function(x) paste('RH%', x))`

Answer (score 44):

Here's how I did it with `facet_grid(yfacet~xfacet)` using ggplot2, version 2.2.1:

```
facet_grid(
    yfacet~xfacet,
    labeller = labeller(
        yfacet = c(`0` = "an y label", `1` = "another y label"),
        xfacet = c(`10` = "an x label", `20` = "another x label")
    )
)
```

Note that this does not contain a call to `as_labeller()` -- something that I struggled with for a while.

This approach is inspired by the last example on the help page [Coerce to labeller function](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/as_labeller.html).

Comment: this works!!! I wasn't able to apply the other solutions because some of the suggested solutions were deprecated on current ggplot2 versions.

Comment: You can construct these named vectors with `setNames()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428439/3362993

Comment: works and is nice and simple

Answer (score 28):

If you have two facets `hospital` and `room` but want to rename just one, you can use:

```
facet_grid( hospital ~ room, labeller = labeller(hospital = as_labeller(hospital_names)))
```

For renaming two facets using the vector-based approach (as in naught101's answer), you can do:

```
facet_grid( hospital ~ room, labeller = labeller(hospital = as_labeller(hospital_names),
                                                 room = as_labeller(room_names)))
```

Comment: This gives NAs for all the labels for me :(

Answer (score 21):

Adding another solution similar to @domi's with parsing mathematical symbols, superscript, subscript, parenthesis/bracket, .etc.

```r
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 18))

### create separate name vectors
# run `demo(plotmath)` for more examples of mathematical annotation in R
am_names <- c(
  `0` = "delta^{15}*N-NO[3]^-{}",
  `1` = "sqrt(x,y)"
)

# use `scriptstyle` to reduce the size of the parentheses &
# `bgroup` to make adding `)` possible 
cyl_names <- c(
  `4` = 'scriptstyle(bgroup("", a, ")"))~T~-~5*"%"',
  `6` = 'scriptstyle(bgroup("", b, ")"))~T~+~10~degree*C',
  `8` = 'scriptstyle(bgroup("", c, ")"))~T~+~30*"%"'
)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_grid(am ~ cyl,
             labeller = labeller(am  = as_labeller(am_names,  label_parsed),
                                 cyl = as_labeller(cyl_names, label_parsed))
             ) +
  geom_text(x = 4, y = 25, size = 4, nudge_y = 1,
            parse = TRUE, check_overlap = TRUE,
            label = as.character(expression(paste("Log"["10"], bgroup("(", frac("x", "y"), ")")))))
```

[image]

```r
### OR create new variables then assign labels directly
# reverse facet orders just for fun
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am2  = factor(am,  labels = am_names),
         cyl2 = factor(cyl, labels = rev(cyl_names), levels = rev(attr(cyl_names, "names")))
  )

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_grid(am2 ~ cyl2,
             labeller = label_parsed) +
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 30, size = 5,
           parse = TRUE, 
           label = as.character(expression(paste("speed [", m * s^{-1}, "]"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: [See also](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/136237_170402e5f0b54561bf7605bdea98267a.html)

Answer (score 18):

Simple solution (from [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/as_labeller.html)):

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) + geom_point()
# Example (old labels)
p + facet_wrap(~am)


to_string <- as_labeller(c(`0` = "Zero", `1` = "One"))
# Example (New labels)
p + facet_wrap(~am, labeller = to_string)
```

Answer (score 12):

This solution is very close to what @domi has, but is designed to shorten the name by fetching first 4 letters and last number.

```
library(ggplot2)

# simulate some data
xy <- data.frame(hospital = rep(paste("Hospital #", 1:3, sep = ""), each = 30),
                 value = rnorm(90))

shortener <- function(string) {
  abb <- substr(string, start = 1, stop = 4) # fetch only first 4 strings
  num <- gsub("^.*(\\d{1})$", "\\1", string) # using regular expression, fetch last number
  out <- paste(abb, num) # put everything together
  out
}

ggplot(xy, aes(x = value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(hospital ~ ., labeller = labeller(hospital = shortener))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Both `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` also accept input from `ifelse` as an argument. So if the variable used for faceting is logical, the solution is very simple:

```
facet_wrap(~ifelse(variable, "Label if true", "Label if false"))
```

If the variable has more categories, the `ifelse` statement needs to be [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016872/6219179).

As a side effect, this also allows the creation of the groups to be faceted within the `ggplot` call.

Answer (score 9):

Note that this solution will not work nicely in case ggplot will show less factors than your variable actually contains (which could happen if you had been for example subsetting):

```
 library(ggplot2)
 labeli <- function(variable, value){
  names_li <- list("versicolor"="versi", "virginica"="virg")
  return(names_li[value])
 }

 dat <- subset(iris,Species!="setosa")
 ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Length)) + stat_bin() + facet_grid(Species ~ ., labeller=labeli)
```

A simple solution (besides adding all unused factors in names_li, which can be tedious) is to drop the unused factors with droplevels(), either in the original dataset, or in the labbeler function, see:

```
labeli2 <- function(variable, value){
  value <- droplevels(value)
  names_li <- list("versicolor"="versi", "virginica"="virg")
  return(names_li[value])
}

dat <- subset(iris,Species!="setosa")
ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Length)) + stat_bin() + facet_grid(Species ~ ., labeller=labeli2)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me.

Define a factor:

```
hospitals.factor<- factor( c("H0","H1","H2") )
```

and use, in `ggplot()`:

```
facet_grid( hospitals.factor[hospital] ~ . )
```

Answer (score 3):

I have another way to achieve the same goal without changing the underlying data:

```
ggplot(transform(survey, survey = factor(survey,
        labels = c("Hosp 1", "Hosp 2", "Hosp 3", "Hosp 4"))), aes(x = age)) +
  stat_bin(aes(n = nrow(h3),y=..count../n), binwidth = 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent", breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2)) +
  facet_grid(hospital ~ .) +
  opts(panel.background = theme_blank())
```

What I did above is changing the labels of the factor in the original data frame, and that is the only difference compared with your original code.

Answer (score 3):

The labeller function defintion with `variable, value` as arguments would not work for me. Also if you want to use expression you need to use lapply and can not simply use `arr[val]`, as the argument to the function is a data.frame.

This code did work:

```
libary(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)
arr <- list('virginica'=TeX("x_1"), "versicolor"=TeX("x_2"), "setosa"=TeX("x_3"))
mylabel <- function(val) { return(lapply(val, function(x) arr[x])) }
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Species, labeller=mylabel)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not yet allowed to comment on posts, I'm posting this separately as an addendum to [Vince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473306) and [son520804's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896753) . Credit goes to them.

> Son520804:
>
> using Iris data:
>
> I assume:
>   You have installed the dplyr package, which has the convenient mutate command, and
>   your dataset is named survey.
>   `survey %>% mutate(Hosp1 = Hospital1, Hosp2 = Hospital2,........)`
>   This command helps you to rename columns, yet all other columns are kept.
>   Then do the same facet_wrap, you are fine now.

Using the iris example of Vince and the partial code of son520804, I did this with the mutate function and achieved an easy solution without touching the original dataset.
The trick is to create a stand-in name vector and use mutate() inside the pipe to correct the facet names temporarily:

```
i <- iris

levels(i$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"

new_names <- c(
  rep("Bristle-pointed iris", 50), 
  rep("Poison flag iris",50), 
  rep("Virginia iris", 50))

i %>% mutate(Species=new_names) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Petal.Length))+
    stat_bin()+
    facet_grid(Species ~ .)
```

In this example you can see the levels of i$Species is temporarily changed to corresponding common names contained in the new_names vector. The line containing

```
mutate(Species=new_names) %>%
```

can easily be removed to reveal the original naming.

**Word of caution:** This may easily introduce errors in names if the new_name vector is not correctly set up. It would probably be much cleaner to use a separate function to replace the variable strings. Keep in mind that the new_name vector may need to be repeated in different ways to match the order of your original dataset. Please double - and - triple check that this is correctly achieved.

Comment: It may be a bit nicer to use: `new_names <- c('setosa' = 'Bristle-pointed iris', 'versicolor' = 'Poison flag iris', 'virginica' = 'Virginia iris')` and then in the mutate you could create a new column thusly: `mutate(Spec = new_names[Species])`

Answer (score 2):

Just extending naught101's answer -- credit goes to him

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value, facetVar1='<name-of-1st-facetting-var>', var1NamesMapping=<pass-list-of-name-mappings-here>, facetVar2='', var2NamesMapping=list() )
{
  #print (variable)
  #print (value)
  if (variable==facetVar1) 
    {
      value <- as.character(value)
      return(var1NamesMapping[value])
    } 
  else if (variable==facetVar2) 
    {
      value <- as.character(value)
      return(var2NamesMapping[value])
    } 
  else 
    {
      return(as.character(value))
    }
}
```

What you have to do is create a list with name-to-name mapping

```
clusteringDistance_names <- list(
  '100'="100",
  '200'="200",
  '300'="300",
  '400'="400",
  '600'="500"
)
```

and redefine `plot_labeller()` with new default arguments:

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value, facetVar1='clusteringDistance', var1NamesMapping=clusteringDistance_names, facetVar2='', var1NamesMapping=list() )
```

And then:

```
ggplot() + 
  facet_grid(clusteringDistance ~ . , labeller=plot_labeller)
```

Alternatively you can create a dedicated function for each of the label changes you want to have.

Answer (score 2):

I think all other solutions are really helpful to do this, but there is yet another way.

I assume:

- you have installed the `dplyr` package, which has the convenient `mutate` command, and
- your dataset is named `survey`.

  survey %>%
    mutate(Hosp1 = Hospital1, Hosp2 = Hospital2,........)

This command helps you to rename columns, yet all other columns are kept.

Then do the same `facet_wrap`, you are fine now.

Comment: sorry, it does not work as it also changes the column content

Comment: This is incorrect, as:

1. the different Hosp1, Hosp2... variables do not exist. The original question uses one single column called "hospital" in which the strings are contained

2. even if you had different columns, your command would look for objects called Hospital1, Hospital2, etc. and would throw an error because they don't exist.

3. as @Jens said, if you used strings instead, i.e. "Hospital1", it would fill the whole column with that value.

You might be looking for a `mutate()` combined with a `case_when()`?
Not sure why this was upvoted as it definitely would not work.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I should add my answer to this because it took me quite long to make this work:

This answer is for you if:

- you do **not** want to edit your original data
- if you need **expressions** (`bquote`) in your labels and
- if you want the flexibility of a separate **labelling name-vector**

I basically put the labels in a named vector so labels would not get confused or switched. The `labeller` expression could probably be simpler, but this at least works (improvements are very welcome). Note the ` (back quotes) to protect the facet-factor.

```
n <- 10
x <- seq(0, 300, length.out = n)

# I have my data in a "long" format
my_data <- data.frame(
  Type = as.factor(c(rep('dl/l', n), rep('alpha', n))),
  T = c(x, x),
  Value = c(x*0.1, sqrt(x))
)

# the label names as a named vector
type_names <- c(
  `nonsense` = "this is just here because it looks good",
  `dl/l` = Linear~Expansion~~Delta*L/L[Ref]~"="~"[%]", # bquote expression
  `alpha` = Linear~Expansion~Coefficient~~alpha~"="~"[1/K]"
  )


ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = my_data, mapping = aes(T, Value)) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Type, scales="free_y", 
             labeller = label_bquote(.(as.expression(
               eval(parse(text = paste0('type_names', '$`', Type, '`')))
               )))) +
  labs(x="Temperature [K]", y="", colour = "") +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for a while, what I found is that we can use `fct_relevel()` and `fct_recode()` from `forcats` in conjunction to change the order of the facets as well fix the facet labels. I am not sure if it's supported by design, but it works! Check out the plots below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

before <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class)
before
```

[image]

```r
after <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(
    vars(
      # Change factor level name
      fct_recode(class, "motorbike" = "2seater") %>% 
        # Change factor level order
        fct_relevel("compact")
    )
  )
after
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A one liner from [mishabalyasin](https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-sep-in-labeller/7369/2?u=samuel.saari)
:

`facet_grid(.~vs, labeller = purrr::partial(label_both, sep = " #"))`

See it in action

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=gear,fill=factor(gear), group=am)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_grid(.~vs, labeller = purrr::partial(label_both, sep = " #"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the specific levels of your `Hospital` vector?

```
levels(survey$hospital)[levels(survey$hospital) == "Hospital #1"] <- "Hosp 1"
levels(survey$hospital)[levels(survey$hospital) == "Hospital #2"] <- "Hosp 2"
levels(survey$hospital)[levels(survey$hospital) == "Hospital #3"] <- "Hosp 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this issue these days is to use `dplyr::case_when` to produce a labeler within the `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` function. This is an extension of the solution proposed by @lillemets

```
ggplot(survey, aes(x = age)) + stat_bin(aes(n = nrow(h3), y = ..count.. / n), binwidth = 10)
  + scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent", breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2))
  + facet_grid(case_when(hospital == "Hospital #1" ~ "Hosp1",
                         hospital == "Hospital #2" ~ "Hosp2") ~ .)
  + theme(panel.background = theme_blank())
```

What's nice is that if you have a second facet label to change you just use the same approach on the other side of the `~` within `facet_grid`

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple way to assign the values to an existing vector without the need for `` c=(`1`="first name",`2`="second name") `` etc.

First create a labeller function

```
title_labeller_function <- function(nuisance_parameter) {
  return(vector_of_labels) 
}
```

,where `vector_of_labels` are your labels, eg. `c("first label", "second label")`

Then just assign this in your `facet_grid/facet_wrap`

```
facet_grid(.~ hospital,labeller=as_labeller(title_labeller_function))
```

For more info, see [as_labeller-documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/as_labeller.html).