# Create a numeric vector with names in one statement?

Tags: r

I'm trying to set the default value for a function parameter to a named numeric.  Is there a way to create one in a single statement?  I checked ?numeric and ?vector but it doesn't seem so.  Perhaps I can convert/coerce a matrix or data.frame and achieve the same result in one statement?  To be clear, I'm trying to do the following in one shot:

```
test = c( 1 , 2 )
names( test ) = c( "A" , "B" )
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The convention for naming vector elements is the same as with lists:

```
newfunc <- function(A=1, B=2) { body}  # the parameters are an 'alist' with two items
```

If instead you wanted this to be a parameter that was a named vector (the sort of function that would handle arguments supplied by `apply`):

```
newfunc <- function(params =c(A=1, B=2) ) { body} # a vector wtih two elements
```

If instead you wanted this to be a parameter that was a named list:

```
newfunc <- function(params =list(A=1, B=2) ) { body} 
    # a single parameter (with two elements in a list structure
```

Comment: Ah!  I never tried that notation because I thought it was limited to lists and data.frames

Comment: This answer contains the answer from [@joran](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7535458/1175496) , but it's hard to tell because it's hidden in here: `function(params= ...) { body }`

Comment: I think we read the question differently. I thought the question was about function parameters. joran thought the question was about naming list or vector items. It is kind of s distinction without a big difference because function parameters are a type of list.

Comment: Actually I don't understand this answer: Maybe a concrete case for `body` and how to use `newfunc` to get the requested data structure would be helpful.

Comment: I answered the question (which didn't ask for a use case and rather only asked for syntactic possibilities.) If this you need this for a specific action, should post a question with data and say what you need done.

Comment: I got a downvote on this that I don't understand. My use of `body` was to indicate that It really didn't matter what was in the function code. The question was only about how to set up defaults for function _parameters_.

Answer (score 150):

The `setNames()` function is made for this purpose. As described in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) and `?setNames`:

```
test <- setNames(c(1, 2), c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 73):

How about:

```
 c(A = 1, B = 2)
A B 
1 2
```

Comment: Plus one for the most straightforward approach to creating a named vector.

Comment: You can also use strings as names by using quotes

Answer (score 69):

...as a side note, the `structure` function allows you to set ALL attributes, not just names:

```
structure(1:10, names=letters[1:10], foo="bar", class="myclass")
```

Which would produce

```
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
attr(,"foo")
[1] "bar"
attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
```

Answer (score 6):

magrittr offers a nice and clean solution.

```
result = c(1,2) %>% set_names(c("A", "B"))
print(result)
A B 
1 2
```

You can also use it to transform data.frames into vectors.

```
df = data.frame(value=1:10, label=letters[1:10])
vec = extract2(df, 'value') %>% set_names(df$label)
vec
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
df
    value label
 1      1     a
 2      2     b
 3      3     c
 4      4     d
 5      5     e
 6      6     f
 7      7     g
 8      8     h
 9      9     i
 10    10     j
```

Comment: The simplest if you want the names to be the same as the vector ie `c(1,2) %>%set_names(.)`

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon @joran's answer (I couldn't get this to format correctly as a comment): If the named vector is assigned to a variable, the values of A and B are accessed via subsetting using the `[` function. Use the names to subset the vector the same way you might use the index number to subset:

```
my_vector = c(A = 1, B = 2)    
my_vector["A"] # subset by name  
# A  
# 1  
my_vector[1] # subset by index  
# A  
# 1
```