# setNames for rows and columns?

Tags: r, matrix, row

I'm trying to write a function that returns a matrix with named rows and columns, and I'm looking for a more succinct solution than:

```
m <- get_matrix()
rownames(m) <- c('the', 'row', 'names')
colnames(m) <- c('the', 'col', 'names')
return (m)
```

I recently learned about the [setNames function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428439/1530508), which creates a copy of a vector or list with its names set. This is exactly the sort of functionality I need, but it doesn't work for `matrix.` Is there a function like `setNames` that works for two-dimensional data types?

Comment: Maybe `"dimnames<-"(m, list(rownames, colnames))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [structure](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/structure.html) function to set the [dimnames attribute](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dimnames.html):

```
return (structure(get_matrix(), dimnames=list(c('the', 'row', 'names'), c('the', 'col', 'names'))))
```

To set only row names:

```
return (structure(get_matrix(), dimnames=list(c('the', 'row', 'names'))))
```

To set only column names:

```
return (structure(get_matrix(), dimnames=list(NULL, c('the', 'col', 'names'))))
```