# What is the shortest way to create an empty named numeric vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, named

I can create an empty vector with `v <- numeric(0)`, but the vector is not named, just of type `num` then. When I evaluate `names(v) <- character(0)`, I have an empty named numeric vector:

```
> v <- numeric(0)
> names(v) <- character(0)
> str(v)
 Named num(0) 
 - attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
> v["test"] <- 1
> str(v)
 Named num 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "test"
```

Is there an easier way to create the empty named numeric vector? It seems there is no constructor like `named(0)`, or did I miss it?

Comment: Actually I found an answer before submitting the question ,but I decided to do it anyway and answer it for your delight...

Comment: Why would you want to create an empty vector? `R` does not really work like that when it comes to iterating

Comment: @Sotos: If you loop over data, conditionally adding to the vector, you want an empty vector at the end of the loop at least (if no condition was true).

Comment: @U.Windl Looping over data, conditionally adding to a vector is something you shouldn't be doing. I've never had a task that couldn't be solved more efficiently and elegantly.

Comment: @Roland, you might be smarter than I am, but if someone asks for something, don't question the need (unless I would have asked whether there is a way to avoid having an empty vector). What you make is a statement (true or false), but not an answer.

Comment: @U.Windl I regularly question the needs of people asking question's here. Usually I'm right doing that. The reason is not being smarter, but being more experienced in R.

Comment: @Roland: IMHO most of the problems in R arise from the fact that developers thought users won't use this or that. Maybe pick a book on mathematics where empty sets appear, and convince the author that there is no need for empty sets. It's also going to be interesting for the recursive definition of a list...

Answer (score 2):

Answers that can be derived from [Create a numeric vector with names in one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535412/create-a-numeric-vector-with-names-in-one-statement) are:

1. Using `structure()`.
2. Using `setNames()`.

For example:

```
> v <- structure(numeric(0), names=character(0))
> str(v)
 Named num(0) 
 - attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 


> v <-setNames(numeric(0), character(0))
> str(v)
 Named num(0) 
 - attr(*, "names")= chr(0)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem useful. Why would an empty vector need a names attribute? You can always add names on the fly: `x <- numeric(); x["a"] <- 1`. But if you want to code-golf, here is an option: `c(a=.1)[-1]`.

Comment: @Roland: Before giving negative credits with such a comment, please add such a comment to the question, and not to the answer.
Despite of that your "answer" does the trick, but I fail to understand it. If your intention is to teach, please add some background letting me understand your solution.
OK, I think I got it: You create a (name, value) pair in a vector and immediately discard that element (the first one). Tricky, but I think my answer is more direct, even if longer.

Comment: Are you really arguing about where I leave a comment? I haven't given "negative credits" (yet) to either the question or answer. However, voting on posts whichever way they want is any user's prerogative.