# How to change facet labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the facet labels in ggplot2.  I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels)

but it is not working for me.  Here is the code I am using

```
facets <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

names <- list(
  '1'="one",
  '2'="two",
  '3'="three",
  '4'="four",
  '5'="five"
)

name_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(names[value])
}

ggplot(Data[Data$Names %in% facets,], aes(y = y, x = x, group = Names)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size=3, aes(fill=Part)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray90","gray40")) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se= FALSE, size = 1, aes(color = Part, group = Part)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black")) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', size = 1, colour = 'red', se = FALSE)  +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(Names ~ ., labeller=name_labeller)
```

When I run this, the facets on the plot read "one" "three" "four" "[empty]" and "[empty]" (i.e. the last two facets are not labelled), instead of "one" "two" "three" "four" and "five".  Also, it's assigning "three" to facet 2 and "four" to facet three.

**Note:** If I change the order of the items in the list "names", this affects the facets that are labelled.  It seems there is an issue with the `name_labeller` not returning the correct word, OR `labeller-name_labeller` isn't asking for the correct thing?

This solution linked above is from 2010, perhaps ggplot2 has changed since then?  Does anyone know how I can change the facet labels on this plot?

Many thanks!

EDIT:  Also, I would like to display the text in italics if possible, e.g. "*one*" "*two*" "*three*" "*four*" "*five*".  I was going to tackle that once I could actually change the facets, but if anyone knows offhand, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Why you have facet_grid() and facet_wrap() in one plot?? You should use only one of them.

Comment: Also it is hard to help in your particular case because we don't have your Data and can't test your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response Didzis!  Thanks for point out the problem with having facet_grid() and facet_wrap() in the code.  I removed facet_wrap(), and now three of the labels are showing up, but in the wrong facet, e.g. it's showing "one" "three" and "four" on the top 3 facets.  I will edit my original post to reflect this.

Comment: As Didzis explained, we really can't help much without being able to run code that generates the behavior you describe. You need to create a small reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks joran!  Alas, the above code is working PERFECTLY for me in my small reproducible example... Argh!  Maybe there is some problem with my input data, I will play around and update if I can figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: OK, I seem to have arrived as an (unsatisfactory) solution to the problem. It seems that some of the additional data in my dataframe that I am not plotting (other Data$Names values that are not included in my list "facets") are causing this problem.  If I remove those data from the input csv file, then the facets are renamed properly.  However, this isn't a satisfactory solution as I don't want to have to use two different input files and dataframes.  I will keep working to see if I can get a working example so we can figure out what is causing this.  Thanks Didzis and joran for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have discovered the problem.  I have a grouping variable in my dataframe called `Part`, and this has empty values for some of the other data that were not included in my plot (these are other values for `Data$Names` that were not included in my list called `facets`).  For some reason, even though I was not plotting these data, the empty values were interfering with the faceting.  I filled in these empty values in my data, and the above code now works perfectly.

Thanks to Didzis and joran for their comments, which pushed me to keep working until I got an answer.

Comment: The question you linked to yourself has an answer that discusses this very issue. It is a fundamental one in R when using factors. When you subset something with a factor, _all_ the levels go along for the ride, even if they don't appear in the data.