# ggplot renaming facet labels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've hit a stumbling block in writing a ggplot function. I'm trying to change the facet labels in a ggplot facet_wrap plot.... but its proving trickier than I though it would be....

The data I am using can be accessed here

```
str(ggdata)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Season : Factor w/ 3 levels "Autumn","Spring",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Site   : Factor w/ 27 levels "Afon Cadnant",..: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ Isotope: Factor w/ 4 levels "14CAA","14CGlu",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Time   : int  0 2 5 24 48 72 0 2 5 24 ...
 $ n      : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ mean   : num  100 88.4 80.7 40.5 27.6 ...
 $ sd     : num  0 1.74 2.85 2.58 2.55 ...
 $ se     : num  0 1 1.65 1.49 1.47 ...
```

I have written the following function to create the ggplot which uses the Isotope factor levels to label the facets:

```
plot_func <- function(T) {site_plots <- ggplot(data = T) + geom_point(aes(Time, mean, colour = Season, shape = Season)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Time, mean, colour = Season, linetype = Season)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(Time, mean, ymax = (mean + se), ymin = (mean - se)), width = 2) +
  labs(title = T$Site[1], y = "Percentage of isotope remaining in solution", x = "Time (h)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 24, 48, 72)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,115), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100)) +  
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -5)) + theme(plot.title =  element_text(vjust = -10)) +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~Isotope, ncol =2) 
  print(site_plots)
  ggsave(plot = site_plots, filename = paste(T$Site[1], ".pdf"), 
     path = "C:/Users/afs61d/Dropbox/Academic/R/Practice datasets/Helens_data/Site_Isotope_Season_plots/", 
     width = 9, height = 7, dpi = 300)}
```

Resulting in this lovely graph:

[image]

Which is nice but I want to change the facet labels now...
Having done some poking around google I thought I might be able to use the `labeller` function as an argument to pass to `facet_wrap`. After a frustrating hour I discovered that this only works with `facet_grid`!!!???
So, an alternative method was to change the Factor level names so give me the facet labels that I want::

```
 gdata$Isotope <- revalue(x = ggdata$Isotope, 
c("14CAA" = " 14C Amino Acids", "14CGlu" = "14C Glucose", 
  "14cGlu6P" = "14C Glucose-6-phosphate", "33P" = "33P Phosphate"))
```

This works, but the problem I have now is that I want the numbers in the labels to be super-scripted. Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: I think "labeller" is available for facet_wrap in the development version of ggplot: http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/facet_wrap.html

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks... that would be very useful - how can I install that?

Comment: @eipi10 I don't think `labeller` can be passed to `facet_wrap`... which is the crux of the problem

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `facet_wrap`, which works, but I'm using the development version of ggplot.

Comment: related popular question but for `facet_grid` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manage to sort it out!
Had trouble installing the development version of `ggplot` but after installing `curl` and `devtools` and reinstalling `scales`it worked. I tried @eipi10 answer but couldn't get that to work so I changed the factor label names in a different way:

```
ggdata$Isotope <- factor(ggdata$Isotope, labels = c("NULL^14*C~Amino~Acids", 
"NULL^14*C~Glucose", "NULL^14*C~Glucose-6-phosphate", "NULL^33*P~Phosphate"))
```

I then adjusted the ggplot function to pass `labeller = label_parsed` to the `facet_wrap` function:

```
plot_func <- function(T) {site_plots <- ggplot(data = T) + geom_point(aes(Time, mean, colour = Season, shape = Season)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Time, mean, colour = Season, linetype = Season)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(Time, mean, ymax = (mean + se), ymin = (mean - se)), width = 2) +
  labs(title = T$Site[1], y = "Percentage of isotope remaining in solution", x = "Time (h)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 24, 48, 72)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,115), breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100)) +  
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -5)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = -10)) +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~Isotope, ncol =2, labeller = label_parsed) 
  print(site_plots)
  ggsave(plot = site_plots, filename = paste(T$Site[1], ".pdf"), 
     path = "C:/Users/afs61d/Dropbox/Academic/R/Practice datasets/Helens_data/Site_Isotope_Season_plots/", 
     width = 9, height = 7, dpi = 300)}
```

Passing the `ggdata` to the `plot_func` gives me the below graphs with the correct facet labels.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Set the facet labels to the appropriate expressions, then use the `labeller` function `label_parsed` to ensure that they are displayed properly. Here's an example, using the built-in `iris` data frame:

```
data(iris)
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species)
iris$Species[iris$Species == "virginica"] = "NULL^14*C~Amino~Acids"

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller=label_parsed)
```

You need to add the `NULL` before `^14*C` or you'll get an error due to having `^` as the initial character. `*` and `~` mark the boundaries of each part of the expression, depending on whether you don't or do want a space between each part.

As of this writing (Dec. 12, 2015), you need to use the development version of `ggplot2` for this to work with `facet_wrap`. However, this feature will presumably soon be incorporated into a regular release of the package.

[image]

Comment: neat trick with the "NULL" to enable the initial superscript. But the OP's question was about `facet_wrap`, not `facet_grid`.

Comment: @eipi10 thanks but this wont work with `facet_wrap`... useful to see `label_parsed` in action though

Comment: I've updated to use `facet_wrap`, which also works. I'm using the development version of ggplot (`ggplot2_1.0.1.9003`). Maybe it doesn't work in the latest CRAN release?

Comment: @eipi10 great... how can I get hold of the development version?

Comment: If you don't have the `devtools` package, install it and load it. Then `install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`.

Comment: @eipi10 struggling with that getting the following message: Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/afs61d/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/ggplot2/R/ggplot2.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Comment: This is happening when you try to install the dev version of `ggplot2`?

Comment: @eipi10 yes. Tried to download then it suggested I needed the `curl` package... so did that, which didn't work. So I updated from R3.2.2 to 3.2.3 then installed `curl` then installed the dev version of `ggplot2`. However, I hen get the above message when I run the ggplot function above

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you need to install [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)?

Comment: Done that... not sure what has gone wrong. Will try and uninstall `ggplot2` and start again

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could also use something even simpler such as:

`facet_wrap(factor(Species, levels = c("A", "B", "C"), labels = c("a", "b", "c")) ~.)`