# Facet label merging into a single row ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have created the following plot using ggplot in R:

[image]

the code:

```
ggplot(hola, aes(.fitted, .resid, color=type)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="black") +
       geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color="darkblue")+facet_wrap( type~exp, scales = "free") +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("#5fb772", "#5fabb7"))
```

However, I think the facet_wrap labels look too big and decompensate the overall graphics looking; is there a way to display it in a better looking way? like merging two columns of the df into one? or merging facet labels in a single row?

PD: By the way, using a facet_grid is not an options since X axis from mu and abs are different.

Comment: "to display it in a better looking way"... By "it" you mean graph itself or facet labels?

Comment: How about you merge data by letter (ie., abs F with mu F) and plot them on one graph. Because now colors don't add anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241890/ggplot-renaming-facet-labels-in-facet-wrap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this help?

```
ggplot(hola, aes(.fitted, .resid, color=type)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="black") +
       geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color="darkblue")+
       facet_wrap( type~exp, scales = "free", labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line=FALSE)) +
       scale_color_manual(values=c("#5fb772", "#5fabb7"))
```

Comment: I havent expected the answer would be that easy. didnt know about this argument   in 'facet_wrap'. TY

Answer (score 2):

```
ggplot(hola, aes(.fitted, .resid, color=type)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="black") +
   geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color="darkblue")+
   facet_wrap(paste(type, exp, sep = ":"), scales = "free") +
   scale_color_manual(values=c("#5fb772", "#5fabb7"))
```

This simply makes a new anonymous variable for each level of `type` and `exp` with values of `"abs: exp_F"`, for example. Then there is only one row of labels for each panel.