# Changing the name of a 3rd variable vector in a geom_point scatterplot; ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am creating a scatterplot using ggplot2 in R in which the size and color of the points on the plot correspond to the mean of a 3rd variable.  I have figured out how to get the plot to look the way I want, but I can't figure out how to change the name of the variable that appears in the legend (to something more descriptive, and with spaces).  I've found similar posts for changing [facet labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels): and for changing the title of a [traditional legend in the ggplot2 documentation using scale_color_discrete](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-legend-in-ggplot2), but these options don't seem to work since I am defining the third variable that this legend represents in a different way.  Here is an example:

Generate Data:

```
x<-rnorm(150)
y<-rnorm(150)
d<-cbind.data.frame(x, y)
d$OUT_VAR<-2 + 1.2*d$x + 1.2*d$y
```

Create Plot:

```
plot1<-ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = OUT_VAR, alpha = OUT_VAR)) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(breaks=c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) +
  xlim(-4, 4) +
  ylim(-4, 4) +
  geom_segment(x = -4, xend = 4, y = 0, yend = 0) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, xend = 0, y = -4, yend = 4) +
  theme_classic() + 
  ggtitle("Plotting the value of the outcome
          on the X, Y Plane") +
  xlab("X Variable") +
  ylab("Y Variable") + 
  theme(title = element_text(size = 14)) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 9)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) 

plot1
```

This creates the following plot:

[Sample Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGmbK.jpg)

Instead of 'OUT_VAR', I would like to rename the legend title...maybe something like 'Outcome Variable'.  If a single word would work, I realize I could just rename the vector itself, but this is for a professional publication, so I want to be able to add something more descriptive.  Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: That's where I found all of the info about changing via scale_color_discrete(name =""), which is what I've been trying, but that doesn't work for this.  My guess is that's because the legend is a product of the aesthetics I'm setting in geom_point() rather than some kind of facet or other categorical variable that is part of the base geom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    name = "Outcome Variable") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(breaks=c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    name = "Outcome Variable")
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!