# Removing NAs from ggplot facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I have a `data.frame` I'd like to `ggplot` with `facets`:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
samples <- c("mt1.2m_1","mt1.2m_2","mt1.4m_1","mt1.4m_2","mt1.4m_3","mt1.4m_4","mt1.4m_5","mt1.6m_1","mt1.6m_2","mt1.6m_3","mt1.6m_4","mt1.6m_5",
             "mt2.2m_1","mt2.2m_2","mt2.4m_1","mt2.4m_2","mt2.6m_1","mt2.6m_2",
             "wt.2m_1","wt.2m_2","wt.2m_3","wt.2m_4","wt.2m_1","wt.4m_2","wt.4m_3","wt.4m_4","wt.6m_1","wt.6m_2","wt.6m_3","wt.6m_4")
val <- rnorm(30)

df <- data.frame(sample=samples,val=rnorm(length(samples)),gt2m=NA,gt4m=NA,gt6m=NA,stringsAsFactors=F)
df$replicate <- as.integer(gsub("^.*_","",df$sample,perl=T))
df$gt2m[which(grepl("2m_",df$sample))] <- gsub("_\\d+$","",df$sample[which(grepl("2m_",df$sample))],perl=T)
df$gt4m[which(grepl("4m_",df$sample))] <- gsub("_\\d+$","",df$sample[which(grepl("4m_",df$sample))],perl=T)
df$gt6m[which(grepl("6m_",df$sample))] <- gsub("_\\d+$","",df$sample[which(grepl("6m_",df$sample))],perl=T)

df$gt2m <- factor(df$gt2m,levels=c("mt1.2m","mt2.2m","wt.2m"))
df$gt4m <- factor(df$gt4m,levels=c("mt1.4m","mt2.4m","wt.4m"))
df$gt6m <- factor(df$gt6m,levels=c("mt1.6m","mt2.6m","wt.6m"))

#add error bar values
val.error <- 0.05*mean(abs(df$val))
df$min.val <- df$val-3*val.error
df$low.val <- df$val-val.error
df$max.val <- df$val+3*val.error
df$high.val <- df$val+val.error

#add a factor to color by
df$col.fill <- factor(apply(dplyr::select(df,gt2m,gt4m,gt6m),1,function(x) x[which(!is.na(x))]))
```

I want to facet the plot by the `gt2m`, `gt4m`, and `gt6m` columns - which are sparse. I define a `forumla` for that:

```
facet.formula <- as.formula("~gt2m+gt4m+gt6m")
```

Here's how I'm trying to plot this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,ymin=min.val,lower=low.val,middle=val,upper=high.val,ymax=max.val,col=col.fill,fill=col.fill))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(scales="free_x",facet.formula,ncol=length(levels(df$col.fill)),labeller = function (labels) {
    labels <- lapply(labels, as.character)
    list(do.call(paste, c(labels, list(sep = ":"))))})
```

Which gives me:
[image]

That's almost perfect except for the `NA`s in the `facet` labels.

I tried:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,ymin=min.val,lower=low.val,middle=val,upper=high.val,ymax=max.val,col=col.fill,fill=col.fill))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(scales="free_x",facet.formula,ncol=length(levels(df$col.fill)),labeller = function (labels) {
    labels <- lapply(labels, as.character)
    list(do.call(paste, c(labels[which(labels != "NA")], list(sep = ":"))))})
```

But that gives the same result.

Any idea how to delete these `NA`s from the `facet` labels?

Comment: This is not the expected output? `ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,ymin=min.val,lower=low.val,middle=val,upper=high.val,ymax=max.val,col=col.fill)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity",alpha=0.5)+
  facet_grid(~col.fill)`

Comment: you're right. facet_grid solves it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well i got dirty fix but it is somehow working:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,ymin=min.val,lower=low.val,middle=val,upper=high.val,ymax=max.val,col=col.fill,fill=col.fill))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(scales="free_x",facet.formula,ncol=length(levels(df$col.fill)),labeller = function (labels) {
    labels <- lapply(labels, as.character)
    a <-  do.call(paste, c(labels, list(sep = ":")))
    list(gsub(":NA","",(gsub("NA:","",a))))
    })
```

I have removed `NA:` and `:NA` characters using `gsub()` function, eitherway it does not look very classy but it works...

**OR**

got even better solution using regex:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,ymin=min.val,lower=low.val,middle=val,upper=high.val,ymax=max.val,col=col.fill,fill=col.fill))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(scales="free_x",facet.formula,ncol=length(levels(df$col.fill)),labeller = function (labels) {
    labels <- lapply(labels, as.character)
    a <-  do.call(paste, c(labels, list(sep = ":")))
    list(gsub("\\:NA|NA:","",a))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a quick fix. There is discussion here on renaming facet labels:
[ggplot: How to change facet labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels)

Hopefully that's the right sort of direction