# ggplot2 facet labeller with bquote

Tags: r, ggplot2

Yet another labeller question... I am struggling using math expressions in labellers with `ggplot2` > 3

```
library(ggplot2)

var.lab1 = as_labeller(c(
  "setosa" = "se", 
  "versicolor" = "ve", 
  "virginica" = "vi"
))

var.lab2 = as_labeller(c(
  "setosa" = bquote("Spp"[set]), 
  "versicolor" = bquote("Spp"[ver]), 
  "virginica" = bquote("Spp"[vir])
))
```

This works as expected

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = var.lab1) +
  geom_point()
```

This doesn't work (the labeller has no effect)

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = var.lab2) +
  geom_point()
```

And this works

```
var.lab3 = c(
  "setosa" = bquote("Spp"[set]), 
  "versicolor" = bquote("Spp"[ver]), 
  "virginica" = bquote("Spp"[vir])
)

vlabeller <- function (variable, value) {
  return(var.lab3[value])
}

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = vlabeller) +
  geom_point()
```

But `ggplot2` is unhappy "Warning message: The labeller API has been updated. Labellers taking variable and value arguments are now deprecated. See labellers documentation."

Comment: I would refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58307679/3392714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `label_bquote` and `substr` to get what you want.  No need for a custom labeller.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = label_bquote(cols = "Spp"[.(substr(Species, 1, 3))])) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct for my particular (and simple) example, that's why I have to validate it. Unfortunately, I am working on a bigger (many more facets) "true life" dataset and each facet has a different kind of labeller, some with bquote and others without... So, if there are other propositions I'll be happy.