# Using labeller in facet_grid to label just columns

Tags: r, facet, facet-grid

I am attempting to use the labeller function to label both the columns and rows.

Here is what I have before I use `labeller = label_both`
[image: Before]

Here is what it looks like after:
[image: After]

Here is what I want it to look like:[image: Desired results]

Is there a way to only label columns or rows?s

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438500/786542

Comment: Unable to get that to work. 
Here is what I did:
`mut_names<-c("μ=1e-4","μ=1e-5","μ=1e-6","μ=1e-7","μ=1e-8")`

`ini_size_names<-c("Initial Population Size: 2", "Initial Population Size: 100")`

`labeller = labeller(Mut_Rate=as_labeller(mut_names,label_parsed),
  `Initial Population Size`=(ini_size_names,label_parsed))`

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)