# R's ggplot's geom_point's label : is there any labeller-like solution for "translating" factor values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-point

**Context:**

1. I'm using `R` on `RStudio` to make, out of a `.csv` file (`meu_primeiro_csv`), a basic `ggplot()`;
2. this `.csv` file was imported using `read_csv()`, and I manually entered the type of each column using `col_types = list()`. The types, are, thus, correct;
3. one of these columns is a *categorical variable* and is very important for the `ggplot()` I'm making: `TP_DEPENDENCIA`, since it is used not only on `geom_point()` as `color` and `shape`, but also as `facet_wrap()`;
4. The `TP_DEPENDENCIA` is of `col_factor()` type, and have four possible values: `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. This is a code in which each value stands for a different type of school: `1` = `Federal`, `2` = `Estadual`, `3` = `Municipal`, or `4` = `Privada`. There are no other types of school, and there are no `NA`s, this `col_factor()` is tidy;
5. I managed to translate the `col_factor()` "numbers" to their true "string" meanings on `facet_wrap()` by using the `labeller` parameter, as suggested [by tamtam's answer for "Changing facet labels in face_wrap() ggplot2" on 'Oct 29, 2020'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598667/19314948);
6. However, there is no `labeller` parameter on `geom_point()`, so the legend of the graph to the right shows "4, 2, 3, 1" instead of the names that these codes represent.

**Questions:**

1. how to "translate" the `<fct>` type `TP_DEPENDENCIA` column's number-coded values to their true textual meanings on the graph's legends?
2. is it possible to make what I ask for on question 1 by employing some presentational change like I did on `facet_wrap()`, without changing the values stored on the `.csv` file?

**The problematic graph:**

[image: My ggplot]

**The code that generated the above graph:**

```
ggplot(
  data    = meu_primeiro_csv,
  mapping = aes(y = QT_SALAS_UTILIZADAS, x = QT_MAT_BAS)) +
   geom_point(mapping = aes(color = TP_DEPENDENCIA, shape = TP_DEPENDENCIA)) +
   facet_wrap(~TP_DEPENDENCIA, labeller = labeller(TP_DEPENDENCIA = c(`1` = "Federal", `2` = "Estadual", `3` = "Municipal", `4` = "Privada"))) +
   labs(
     title    = "Educação básica: total de alunos × total de salas",
     subtitle = "Totais por tipo de escola: municipal, estadual, federal, ou privada",
     y        = "Salas utilizadas pela escola",
     x        = "Matrículas na educação básica",
     color    = "Tipo de escola",
     shape    = "Tipo de escola"
   ) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
   scale_color_colorblind()
```

**CSV for reproducible example:**

- [PCO207. MG. Educação Básica. Microdados. 2022. - microdados_ed_basica_2022_MG.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ce-V7UjuJIUsJX57sqDYik8wS0rQ-z-Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You are probably better off mutating TP_DEPENDENCIA into a factor variable that you can then use for the mapping and faceting. Then you wouldn't need a separate custom labeller.

Comment: "You are probably better off mutating TP_DEPENDENCIA into a factor variable that you can then use for the mapping and faceting." It is already a factor variable, as told on point 4 of the "context" section.

Comment: Well, a factor variable with the labels you want since ggplot uses the labels for legends and facets. It seems now you might have numeric labels which is odd. Again, this would be easier with a reproducible example.

Comment: @MrFlick I added the `.csv` to the question. Is it now reproducible enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case_when` to create a new variable in your dataset with the labels for `TP_DEPENDENCIA`. Use the new variable instead of `TP_DEPENDENCIA`, and you'll get the labels in the legend.

```
meu_primeiro_csv %>% 
  mutate(tipo_de_escola = case_when(TP_DEPENDENCIA == 1 ~ "Federal", 
                                    TP_DEPENDENCIA == 2 ~ "Estadual", 
                                    TP_DEPENDENCIA == 3 ~ "Municipal"
                                    TP_DEPENDENCIA == 4 ~ "Privada"
                                    )
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    mapping = aes(y = QT_SALAS_UTILIZADAS, x = QT_MAT_BAS)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = tipo_de_escola, shape = tipo_de_escola)) +
  facet_wrap(~tipo_de_escola) +
  labs(
    title    = "Educação básica: total de alunos × total de salas",
    subtitle = "Totais por tipo de escola: municipal, estadual, federal, ou privada",
    y        = "Salas utilizadas pela escola",
    x        = "Matrículas na educação básica",
    color    = "Tipo de escola",
    shape    = "Tipo de escola"
  ) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  scale_color_colorblind()
```

However, you should consider showing the variable `TP_DEPENDENCIA` with only *one* aesthetic instead of three. Try making the plot where you are only using `TP_DEPENDENCIA` to either facet_wrap, *or* colour, *or* shape. You'll have the same amount of information, and your graph will be simpler. Choose the one you think works best.

Comment: Johan, thank you for your tip about the excessive aesthetics being employed. I started without `facet_wrap()` and was just following https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-visualize , so I did not realize that the `color` and `shape` were not needed since I introduced `facet_wrap()`.