# Change (all) facet_grid strip text

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the (all) label given by `facet_grid` to the strip text if `margins = ...`?

Here is an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() +
    facet_grid(am ~ cyl, margins = "cyl")
```

How can I make `(all)` say `FOO`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893005/how-to-change-strip-text-labels-in-ggplot-with-facet-and-margin-true) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels) are solutions that could help.

Comment: This "(all)" labels seems to be hard-coded, and not even in ggplot2 but in `reshape2::add_margins`. It might be worth opening an issue in github, if it's not already been done.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is a duplicate but I believe that title is terrible and didn't yield a hit for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `labeller` parameter of `facet_grid()`. This is a function that takes two arguments, the variable and value. You can define your own:

```
facet_labels <- function(variable, value) {
  labels <- as.character(value)
  labels[labels == '(all)'] <- 'FOO'
  return (labels)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(am ~ cyl, margins = "cyl", labeller = facet_labels)
```

Comment: Perfect.  I was even already using this to change labels but didn't think to apply it to all.