# facet label font size

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to change the font size of facet labels in `ggplot`? I googled and found that the issue was yet on Hadley's to-do list. I wonder if there is a workaround or any news on this issue?

Comment: It's great that you are enthusiastic, but 4 questions in 4 hours makes me think maybe you aren't taking the time to try and solve your problems yourself.  SO is not meant to completely replace thinking!

Comment: @ Richie Cotton +1 for your comment. Don't worry, I am just trying to do both. I just don't stop thinking while others are thinking. Plus, the r section is relatively small yet, if it was C++ or Java probably nobody would have realized that I was on a frenzy. In fact, it´s basically because I am new to SO – don't worry I will settle down. But hell, you are right – thx for sending me back to earth.

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf I guess rcs realized 8 years ago it was possibly a duplicate. Even though, in the meantime I also think it can be considered a duplicate, I still feel my question's wording is much better -- at least for people googling this -- which is probably why I did not find the 'original' when I was a SO rookie.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
R> qplot(hwy, cty, data = mpg) + 
       facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer) + 
       theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, colour = "orange", angle = 90))
```

See also this question: [How can I manipulate the strip text of facet plots in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751065/how-can-i-manipulate-the-strip-text-of-facet-plots-in-ggplot2/2751201#2751201)

Comment: If on full-customization mode, one may be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261597/can-i-change-the-position-of-the-strip-label-in-ggplot-from-the-top-to-the-botto