# R ggplot2 facet_wrap reordering subfigure and set different colors for each ID label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to reorder the subfigures order in ggplot facet_wrap and specify a certain color for their subfigure text label.

Here is my dataset:

```
  ID <- rep(c('ABC123','DEF456','GHI789','JKL012'),each = 10)
  Vref <- c((runif(10,1,2)),(runif(10,3,5)),(runif(10,6,9)),(runif(10,0,2)))
  Time <- rep(c(1:10),4)
  df <- data.frame(ID,Vref,Time)
  ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Time, y=Vref)) + facet_wrap(~ID, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Now the order of subfigure is ABC123 --> DEF456 --> GHI789 --> JKL012. 
All text labels are in black.

My question is:

How to change the order to GHI789 --> ABC123 --> JKL012 --> DEF456 ?
How to specify the color in red, green, yellow, and blue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to specifying colours for the strip texts is to use editing functions from the `grid` package. Usually `grid.ls()` and other editing functions see just one grob, but `grid.force()` makes all the grobs in the ggplot visible to grid's editing functions.

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

ID <- rep(c('ABC123','DEF456','GHI789','JKL012'),each = 10)
Vref <- c((runif(10,1,2)),(runif(10,3,5)),(runif(10,6,9)),(runif(10,0,2)))
Time <- rep(c(1:10),4)
df <- data.frame(ID,Vref,Time)

# Change order of strip texts
df$ID = factor(df$ID, levels = c("GHI789", "ABC123", "JKL012", "DEF456"))

p = ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Time, y=Vref)) + facet_wrap(~ID, nrow = 2) 

gp <- ggplotGrob(p)  # Get ggplot grob

# Get the names of the grobs
# grid.force makes all the grobs visible to grid's editing functions
names.grobs <- grid.ls(grid.force(gp))$name

# Inspect the list. The required grobs' names begin with GRID.text,
# but so do other text grobs - to do with the axes.
# Therefore, in the edit, use gPath to limit the editing to GRID.text in the strip,
# and not the GRID.text in the axes.

strip.text <- names.grobs[which(grepl("GRID.text", names.grobs))]

# Set up the colours
colour <- c("yellow", "blue", "red", "green")

# The edit
for(i in 1:4) gp = editGrob(grid.force(gp), 
                     gPath("GRID.titleGrob", strip.text[i]), 
                     grep = TRUE,    
                     gp = gpar(col = colour[i]))

# Draw it 
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful post. It helps me a lot. I believe it will also help others.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out these already answered questions:

[How to change the order of facet labels in ggplot (custom facet wrap labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490638/how-to-change-the-order-of-facet-labels-in-ggplot-custom-facet-wrap-labels)

[facet label font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290330/facet-label-font-size)

The ordering can be achieved through a factor, and the coloring of the facet strip is done through a theme as in the following (making the colour orange):

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=Time, y=Vref)) + facet_wrap(~ID, nrow = 2) +
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, colour = "orange"))
```

For colouring each facet strip individually, I don't know of a clean way to do this. I found a similar question that discusss using custom graphics objects (grobs) to modify the background colours of the strips. Here is the link:

[ggplot2: facet_wrap strip color based on variable in data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440069/ggplot2-facet-wrap-strip-color-based-on-variable-in-data-set)

Comment: Thanks for the link! About the issues of the coloring the facet strip, the theme setting is to change the element_text all in one color. However, I want to specify the colors for each individual subfigures.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I missed that earlier. Anyway, I've updated my answer though only to point to a similar SO question. I'm not aware of a clean "aes" way to do this.