# Change facet_wrap() strip positions to place facet strips inside plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

How can I change the `facet_wrap()` strip position as it has shown in below picture?
The data frames is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859487/r-ggplot2-facet-wrap-reordering-subfigure-and-set-different-colors-for-each-id-l) question.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcKcd.jpg)

Comment: Where do you want to have the strip position? Just on the left side?

Comment: They move inside the panels and above the bars at the left side.

Comment: Maybe this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261597/can-i-change-the-position-of-the-strip-label-in-ggplot-from-the-top-to-the-botto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via the [`gggrid`](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/Reports/gggrid/gggrid.html) package. Similar to `ggplot2::annotation_custom` it allows to add grobs to a ggplot but offers much more flexibility, e.g. you could place different grobs to each facet panel. Moreover it allows to access the `data` and `coords` objects created by ggplot2 under the hood and allows to pass additional aesthetics.

Basically it requires a function which creates the grob which are then added to the ggplot via `gggrid::grid_panel`. For the grob I use `gridtext::richtext_grob` which makes it easy to add a strip text like text box to each panel.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gggrid)
#> Loading required package: grid
library(gridtext)

set.seed(123)

ID <- rep(c("ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789", "JKL012"), each = 10)
Vref <- c((runif(10, 1, 2)), (runif(10, 3, 5)), (runif(10, 6, 9)), (runif(10, 0, 2)))
Time <- rep(c(1:10), 4)
df <- data.frame(ID, Vref, Time)

tg <- function(data, coords) {
  y_label <- max(coords$y) 
  gridtext::richtext_grob(data$label[which.max(coords$y)],
    x = unit(0, "npc")  + unit(.045, "npc"),
    y = unit(y_label, "npc") + unit(2, "mm"),
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 0,
    valign = .5,
    padding = unit(rep(4.4, 4), "pt"),
    gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8, fill = "grey85"),
    box_gp = grid::gpar(col = "grey85")
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Vref)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, .2))) +
  facet_wrap(~ID, nrow = 2) +
  gggrid::grid_panel(mapping = aes(label = ID), tg) +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]