# ggplot2 cheat sheet

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are lots of general [R cheat sheets](http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/r/?page=1), but is there a cheat sheet for ggplot2?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258784/list-of-ggplot2-options and https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki

Answer (score 43):

Here are several options:

1. A very polished [`ggplot2` cheat sheet from RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ggplot2-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf) (Dec 2015). This version is updated for [`ggplot2 2.0`](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/).
2. Another [ggplot cheat sheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5094866/rtutorial/notes/ggplot2.pdf).
3. A [ggplot2 tutorial](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/) (October 2014).
4. A 14-page quick reference/tutorial for ggplot2 published in September 2011:
   [ggplot2 tutorial by Ramon Saccilotto](http://www.ceb-institute.org/bbs/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/handout_ggplot2.pdf).
5. A [detailed tutorial](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/avml2012/) on a wide range of plot types and customization options, published in 2012.
6. Winston Chang's Cookbook for R website has a section with [ggplot2 recipes](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/). Also see his [R Graphics Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023135.do) from O'Reilly.
7. A [website with brief tutorials](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2) on the major aspects of ggplot2.
8. The [ggplot2 transition guide](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDUxNTQ3Nzk3MDk5MzYyNTU1ODUBMDQ0NTQ2OTIyMzkwMzE2OTE0NTUBRjB0UW80NnZFblVKATMBAXYy) from February 2012 is longer, but systematically goes through all the features that were changed or added in going from the original version of ggplot2 to the (at the time) latest version.
9. If you're interested in drawing maps with ggplot2, there's [Hadley's article on spatial visualization with ggplot2](http://stat405.had.co.nz/ggmap.pdf). Also see this [detailed tutorial on maps and spatial analysis](http://rpubs.com/RobinLovelace/intro-spatial) with R at rPubs (2014).
10. Detailed examples on [scatterplots](http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2013/11/ggplot2-cheatsheet-for-scatterplots.html), [visualizing distributions](http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2014/02/ggplot2-cheatsheet-for-visualizing.html) (density and box plots), and [barplots](http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2014/01/ggplot2-cheatsheet-for-barplots.html) with ggplot2 (late 2013 - early 2014).
11. A more detailed task based [ggplot2 cheat sheet](http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-cheatsheet.html), or rather a quick reference.

Comment: link 1. does not work.

Comment: It looks like the file is no longer posted anywhere on that site, so I've linked to a different location. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Great to post it here!

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly a cheat sheet, but also helpful in figuring out the right command, is [Jeroen Ooms' web interface to ggplot2](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~jeroen/ggplot2/)

Comment: FYI this link no longer works

Answer (score 4):

To me ggplot2 has one of the best and compressed [documentation](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) of any R package.
I think it would be really difficult pack everything to an even smaller document.
This holds in particular because some of the magic of ggplot2 is closely related to functions from plyr or reshape. Though I have suggested via feedback form that some .pdf reference card would be really nice. Besides I recommend the ggplot2 book.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you are looking for: http://had.co.nz/stat480/r/graphics.html