# How to change barplot in ggplot for R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I have a plot in `ggplot` that shows me for each category of "rating" the level of price in "bank" and "sistem". This is my code:

```
##fict
a<-c("rating1","rating2","rating3")
b<-c(1.2,1.2,1.3)
c<-c(1.6,1.4,1.6)

gg<-cbind('rating'=rep(a,2),'price'=c(b,c),'tipo'=rep(c("bank","sistem"),3))
gg<-as.data.frame(gg)


a<-rgb(red=150, green=191, blue=37, maxColorValue = 255)
b<-rgb(red=80, green=113, blue=14, maxColorValue = 255)


    ggplot(gg, aes(x=tipo, y=price,width=1)) +   
      geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity', fill=c(b,a), color='black') +
      facet_wrap( ~ rating)+
      theme_bw() +  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
       panel.border = element_blank(),
       panel.background = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour = 'white', fill = 'white', size = 3),
    axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.19),
    axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.19)
    #strip.text.x = element_text(colour = 'red', angle = 45, size = 10, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold')
    ) + xlab("My x label") +
      ylab("My y label") +
    labs(title = 'difference')
```

This code generates my plot.

I'd like to change 3 things:

- I'd like that the labels rating shows in the bottom
- I'd like that the "bank" and "sistem" labels disappear and change it with the legend with colors for bank and sistem.
- If it's possible also put the legend under the x-axis title in horizontal way

Thank you

Comment: You can do most of this without faceting. Try `ggplot(gg, aes(x=rating, y=price, fill=tipo)) + geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity', color='black')`. You can change legend position with theme`legend.position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade comment to an answer.

```
library(ggplot2)

# your data - tweaked the code - there is no need to cbind within data.frame
# and names do not need to be in quotes
gg <- data.frame(rating=rep(c("rating1","rating2","rating3"),2),
                 price=c(c(1.2,1.2,1.3),c(1.6,1.4,1.6)),
                 tipo=rep(c("bank","sistem"),3))

a <- rgb(red=150, green=191, blue=37, maxColorValue = 255)
b <- rgb(red=80, green=113, blue=14, maxColorValue = 255)

# Plot

# use position dodge to get the bars side-by-side
# theme_classic removes grid lines and uses theme_bw()
# scale_fill_manual to manually specify the colours - by using fill = tipo in the 
# aesthetic call of ggplot a legend will be generated
# scale_y_continuous - using expand starts the axis at exactly zero


ggplot(gg, aes(x=rating, y=price, fill=tipo)) +   
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity', color='black') +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(b,a)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,2), expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(title = 'difference', x = "My x label", y = "My y label") +
  theme(
      axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.19),
      axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.19) ,
      legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your help. Another question: is there a way to have the legends without slashes?

Comment: Your welcome. The legend gets the slashes due to adding `colour='black'` to the `geom_bar` call. A quick (and ugly) fix is to add a second `geom_bar` call while tweaking the function arguments in both. See [see bottom of the page in this post from the R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/)

Comment: Thank you! Do you now a good tutorial for ggplot? Because looking for that I found only basic tutorials

Comment: There are a couple of books but I think the [ggplot2 help site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) is a good place to start. Also if you know what plot you want or what part of the plot you want to tweak a quick online search will almost definitely lead to a page describing how to do it. Also have a look through the `ggplot2` tag questions that have been asked on SO - there is always something new. I think *learn by doing* is quite a good approach.

Comment: You might find something useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446495/ggplot2-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Now I'm improving my plot. I'm adding:  `geom_text(data=gg,aes(label=price, y = price+0.08, group=tipo),
 size = 4, position = position_dodge(width=0.8))` to have the labels above the bars. The plot looks good but I get the warning: "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead". I have to worry about that? How can I remove it?

Comment: This is a harmless warning, but you can avoid it by adding `ymax=price` to your `geom_text` call. You could rewrite it as `geom_text(aes(ymax=price, label=price), size = 4, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.3)` - slightly less typing as it uses the mapping from the original `ggplot` call.