# Color of gridlines and background

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems that this question [first appeared](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-Change-color-of-grid-lines-td827813.html) around 2007.

The question is this:

How to change the gridline and background color when plotting with ggplot2 in R? I add two pictures as an example of what I mean by background and gridline color.

Back in 2007, Hadley Wickham said that appearance functionalities were missing (this included changing the color of the background). Does anybody know if there's an update that allows changing the background color and the color of the gridlines?

Thanks in advance

[image: before]
[image]

Comment: `theme_bw()` may bundle a lot of what you want together...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 this is done [using](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) `theme`:

```
theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white"))
```

Additionally, there are `panel.grid.major` and `panel.grid.minor` options. See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) for a full list of options and some examples. There is also documentation at `?theme`.

In older version of **ggplot2** this was done via:

```
opts(panel.background=theme_rect(colour="white"),...)
```

You can also switch to more traditional theme using `theme_bw()`.

You can also find information on themes and opts() on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258784/list-of-ggplot2-options) SO thread.

Comment: That changes the color of the background border, not the gridlines. To change the background use `panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")`. To change gridlines use `panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "green")`

Comment: @user2863275 My answer mentions both `panel.grid.major` and `panel.grid.minor`...?

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat hidden option that I find helpful for identifying "where" these things are and what they are called is:

```
theme_get()
```

It shows you both the call and the definitions for all of the theme options. Also, if you're going to be messing about with thematics, you should keep in mind that you can save a number of calls as a list object... for example:

```
plotoptions <- list(opts(x,y,z),scale_fill_manual(...),labs(x,y,z))
someplot + plotoptions
```

I use this a lot when I'm customizing themes to match a corporate style or something of that like.

Comment: Frustratingly, this doesn't show up in the list when you search for ??theme