# How do I look for help on parameters of ggplot2 R package

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of ggplot2 options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258784/list-of-ggplot2-options)

I have a pretty basic question on ggplot2.

When I need to look for help on paramters of plot with base R, I just write

```
?par
```

What's the equivalent of '?par' for ggplot2?

Sometimes I'm using qplot and need to understand hot to tune my geom paramters or another thing, but I just don't know how to look for documentation on the paramters...

Any help?

Comment: Indeed, it's similar. However, I didn't find and SO isn't sugesting it as a related question. Anyway, what should I do?

Comment: My vote to close as a duplicate was not a comment on the worthiness of your question. SO has a question already with pointers to ggplot2 docs, and note that sharpie's answer there is a CW, so it can be added to and updated with further references.

Comment: @ManoelGaldino: Learning to use the search box with the `[r]` tag is useful to avoid dupes.

Comment: I do use [r] tag in my search... And Joran, I don't quite understand what I have to do. Should I vote to close it too? Or I can close it without the need of any vote, since I asked the question?

Comment: So, I voted it to be closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explore these two links

[R Cookbook](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs)

[ggplot2 opts](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/+opts%28%29-List)