# formatting circular area plot with point in ggplot2 using r

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

Here is my plot:

```
gr1 <- c(1, 5, 15, 20, 30, 40)
gr3 <- c(1, 5, 10, 25, 40, 60, 80)
gr2 <- c(1, 15, 25, 30, 40)

df2<- data.frame (pos = c(gr1, gr2, gr3), group = c(rep(1, length(gr1)),
 rep(2, length(gr2)), rep(3, length(gr3))))
df2$cpos <- cumsum (df2$pos)
df2$y <- rep(3, length (df2$cpos))
df2$y1 <- rep(0.35, length (df2$cpos))

df3 <- data.frame (cpos = rep(df2$cpos, 2), 
group = rep(df2$group,2), yd = c(df2$y, df2$y1),
x2 = c(rep(1, length (df2$y)),
rep(2, length (df2$y1))))

cx <- ggplot(df3, aes(y = yd, x = cpos, fill=factor(x2)))
cx1 <- cx + geom_area(aes(stat = "identity", position="fill" ))
cx1 +  geom_point(aes(color = factor(group)), pch = 19, size = 4) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "yellow", "green")) + coord_polar()
```

[image]

I could not get rid of some of issues

(1) I could not change color of the points, color change only applied to circles.

(2) the plot additional points plotted at the center circle, which I do not want to plot. (they are additional csum points)

declaration: this post is related with the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467988/modified-polar-plot-using-ggplots-or-other-alternative-packages-using-r)

## Bonus accidental art

As am working hard to solve the issues, I do an sunflower plot.

```
df2<- data.frame (pos = c(gr1, gr2, gr3), group = c(rep(1, length(gr1)),
 rep(2, length(gr2)), rep(3, length(gr3))))
df2$cpos <- cumsum (df2$pos)
df2$y <- rep(3, length (df2$cpos))
df2$y1 <- rep(0.01, length (df2$cpos))
df2$y3 <- rep(2, length (df2$cpos))

df3 <- data.frame (cpos = rep(df2$cpos, 3), group = c(rep(1, length (df2$y)),
 rep(2, length (df2$y)), rep(3, length (df2$y))),
 yd = c(df2$y, df2$y1, df2$y3), x3 = c(rep(1, length (df2$y)), 
 rep(2, length (df2$y1)),rep(2, length (df2$y1)) ))
```

## makes flower

```
cx <- ggplot(df3, aes(y = yd, x = cpos, fill=factor(x3)))
cx1 <- cx + geom_area(aes(stat = "identity", position="fill" ))
cx2 <- cx1 +  geom_point(aes(color = factor(group)), pch = 19, size = 4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "pink")) + coord_polar()
cx2 + theme_bw()+ opts(axis.line=theme_blank(),axis.text.y=theme_blank(),
 axis.ticks = theme_blank(), axis.title.y=theme_blank(), 
 plot.background=theme_blank(), panel.border=theme_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: ggplot makes a distinction between `color` and `fill`. You specify a `color` in your geom `aes()`, but a `fill` in the scale. Use `scale_color_manual` to fix your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, is this what you want? The inner circle of points correspond to `yd = 0.35` or `x2 = 2`  in the df3 data frame. Therefore, in the `geom_point` call, drop those points from the df3 data frame. Here, I've use `subset`.

```
# Your data
gr1 <- c(1, 5, 15, 20, 30, 40)
gr3 <- c(1, 5, 10, 25, 40, 60, 80)
gr2 <- c(1, 15, 25, 30, 40)

df2<- data.frame (pos = c(gr1, gr2, gr3), group = c(rep(1, length(gr1)),
 rep(2, length(gr2)), rep(3, length(gr3))))
df2$cpos <- cumsum (df2$pos)
df2$y <- rep(3, length (df2$cpos))
df2$y1 <- rep(0.35, length (df2$cpos))

df3 <- data.frame (cpos = rep(df2$cpos, 2), 
  group = rep(df2$group,2), yd = c(df2$y, df2$y1),
  x2 = c(rep(1, length (df2$y)),
  rep(2, length (df2$y1))))

# The plot
library(ggplot2)
cx <- ggplot(df3, aes(y = yd, x = cpos, fill=factor(x2)))
cx1 <- cx + geom_area(aes(stat = "identity", position="fill" ))
cx1 +  geom_point(data = subset(df3, x2 == 1), aes(color = factor(group)), 
  pch = 19, size = 4) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "yellow", "green"))  + coord_polar()
```

The result is:

[image]